# Use ListFragment to get items from databasee

Tags: java, android, android-listfragment

I am encountering a problem where I could not display my data from database in the listfragment. Currently I am using SimpleCursorAdapter to display my data but then once i click on my button it says no data.

This is my MovieListFragment extends ListFragment code:

```
package com.example.moviemanager;

import android.database.Cursor;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.ListFragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class MovieListFragment extends ListFragment {
    DatabaseHandler dh = new DatabaseHandler(getActivity());
    private static final String ROW_ID = "row_id";
    private listMovieActivity parent;


    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.displaymoviemenu, container, false);
        parent = (listMovieActivity) getActivity();
        populateListViewFromDB();

        return v;
    }


    private void openDB() {
        dh.open();
    }

    private void closeDB() {
        dh.close();
    }

    private void populateListViewFromDB() {
        Cursor cursor = dh.getAllRows();

        // Allow activity to manage lifetime of the cursor.
        // DEPRECATED! Runs on the UI thread, OK for small/short queries.
        getActivity().startManagingCursor(cursor);

        // Setup mapping from cursor to view fields:
        String[] fromFieldNames = new String[]
                {dh.KEY_KEY, dh.KEY_TITLE};
        int[] toViewIDs = new int[]
                {R.id.txtMovieId, R.id.txtMovieTitleRow};

        // Create adapter to may columns of the DB onto elemesnt in the UI.
        SimpleCursorAdapter myCursorAdapter;
        myCursorAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(
                getActivity(),// Context
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,    // Row layout template
                cursor,                 // cursor (set of DB records to map)
                fromFieldNames,         // DB Column names
                toViewIDs               // View IDs to put information in
        );

        // Set the adapter for the list view
        ListView movieList = (ListView) getView().findViewById(android.R.id.list);
        movieList.setAdapter(myCursorAdapter);
    }

    @Override
    public void onListItemClick(ListView list, View view, int position, long id) {
        // TODO: show detail depending on activity
        String a=list.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
        System.out.println(a);
        parent.showDetails(position,a);
    }


    private void displayToastForId(long idInDB) {
        Cursor cursor = dh.getRow(idInDB);
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            long idDB = cursor.getLong(dh.COL_ROWID);
            String mvkey = cursor.getString(dh.COL_KEY);
            String mvtitle = cursor.getString(dh.COL_TITLE);
            //String favColour = cursor.getString(DBAdapter.COL_FAVCOLOUR);

            String message = "ID: " + idDB + "\n"
                    + "Name: " + mvtitle + "\n"
                    + "Key#: " + mvkey;
            //+ "FavColour: " + favColour;
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        cursor.close();
    }
}
```

This is the error code:

```
   04-03 13:31:00.745    6713-6713/com.example.moviemanager E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.moviemanager/com.example.moviemanager.listMovieActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #7: Error inflating class fragment
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #7: Error inflating class fragment
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:270)
            at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1881)
            at com.example.moviemanager.listMovieActivity.onCreate(listMovieActivity.java:20)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getDatabaseLocked(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:224)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:164)
            at com.example.moviemanager.DatabaseHandler.open(DatabaseHandler.java:65)
            at com.example.moviemanager.MovieListFragment.openDB(MovieListFragment.java:32)
            at com.example.moviemanager.MovieListFragment.onCreateView(MovieListFragment.java:24)
            at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1478)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:900)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1082)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.addFragment(FragmentManager.java:1184)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:285)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:676)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:270)
            at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1881)
            at com.example.moviemanager.listMovieActivity.onCreate(listMovieActivity.java:20)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-03 13:31:02.795    6733-6733/com.example.moviemanager E/Trace﹕ error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
```

Comment: show total fragment code

Comment: i have added the whole fragment code @NoName

Comment: Try to use just Fragment instead! and find the list view in onCreateView method.

Comment: please make sure if you are closing the db after opening, as from your error log it seems that  your database is opened somewhere and you are accessing it again without closing the previously opened db.  And also your openDB() method seems to be not called anywhere.

Comment: My app still crashes

Answer (score 0):

try the following method:
1. By default this listfragment contains the list view, so no need to inflate the view.

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.ListFragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

/**
 * Created by android on 3/4/15.
 */
public class TestFragment extends ListFragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
    }


    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        setListAdapter(//here pass t he adapter);
    }
}
```

Comment: how to pass the adapter to method onStart()?

Comment: call this method populateListViewFromDB();  in onstart();

Comment: my application still crashing

Answer (score 0):

You are putting the data in ListFragment listview with android.R.id.list, so you have to use setListAdapter(adapter) as indicated No Name in the previous comment. Also you have to define this in the xml:

`<ListView
            android:id="@id/android:list"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"/>`

Edit: Override onViewCreated method and put there the DB query  method and add the adapter to ListFragment.